# Can Camel protect against acting on files which are open by some other process?

Tags: apache-camel

Mule has two features on a File transport which protect against acting on files which are currently open by another process.  These are fileAge, which check to make sure that the last modified time on the file is greater than some specified time, and a size check wait time feature which specifies an interval over which the file size must not change.

I can't find equivalent features in Camel.  Is there a way to protect against Camel acting on files which are open by some other process?  More specifically, how can I protect against having my SFTP pick up a file that someone is currently writing on their SFTP server.

Answer (score 0):

The [file2](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) component documentation describes the different readLock strategies and which ones should work with the (s)ftp component and which ones don't.